# Getting active view in react-native iOS native modules

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How do we get the current active view in react-native iOS native modules? For Android, the `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` includes a `getCurrentActivity()` . What's the similar method for iOS native modules?

Comment: Are you using any Navigator in your app ?

Comment: No I'm not using any navigator.. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can do with:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;
```

(not forget to 
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`)